# ReferenceError: google is not defined at drawChart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have used arrayToDataTable with the data "inside" the call.
Now, I am trying to define the data (timeAndNote) "outside" the function, like this. But I get a reference error: *google is not defined  at drawChart*

```
var timeAndNote = [
['time','note']
[-3,  83],
[-2,  60.5],
[-1,  66],
[0,  67]
];
drawChart(timeAndNote);

function drawChart(array) {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array, true);

  var options = {
    title: 'note vs time',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' },
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [
      ---removed ---      
      ]
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));


  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what this means?

Comment: it means you're trying to use the `google.visualization` namespace, before google charts has been fully loaded. will you please share the code where google charts is loaded?

Comment: Thanks, I understand now